# Memory leak in PHP with Symfony + Doctrine

Tags: php, memory-leaks, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using PHP with the Symfony framework (with Doctrine as my ORM) to build a spider that crawls some sites.

My problem is that the following code generates a memory leak:

```
$q = $this -> createQuery('Product p');

if($store) {
    $q
        -> andWhere('p.store_id = ?', $store -> getId())
        -> limit(1);
}

$q -> andWhere('p.name = ?', $name);

$data = $q -> execute();
$q -> free(true);
$data -> free(true);
return NULL;
```

This code is placed in a subclass of `Doctrine_Table`. If I comment out the execute part (and of course the `$data -> free(true)`) the leak stops. This has led me to the conclusion that it's the `Doctrine_Collection` that's causing the leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problems with Doctrine memory leaks by freeing *and* unseting data, did you try it?

```
// ...
$data->free(true) ;
unset($data) ;
// ...
```

Comment: That actually worked! Weird, PHP should clean that up by itself.
Still gonna use CakePHP instead, it feels better :)

I can add that I did do unset($q) aswell.

Answer (score 1):

What version of PHP are you using? If it's < 5.3 it probably has to do with the ['recursive references leak memory'](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33595) bug.

You can also try to call `Doctrine_Manager::connection()->clear()`, which should clean up the connection and remove identity map entries

Comment: I'm using 5.3.2.
Are you sure Doctrine_Manager::connection()->clean() is correct? I can't find it in the API and I can't call it.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using addWhere instead of andWhere?  Also I believe a limit should be added at the end of a statement, try:

```
$q = $this -> createQuery('Product p') -> where('p.name = ?', $name);

 if($store) {
$q
    -> addWhere('p.store_id = ?', $store -> getId())
    -> limit(1);
 }

 $data = $q -> execute();
 $q -> free(true);
 $data -> free(true);
return NULL;
```

Comment: addWhere and andWhere are synonyms of each other and work the same, your changes made no difference on the memory leak.

Comment: Cool, didnt know that about add/andWhere, sorry I couldnt be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just running into the same problem with a CLI command that runs continuously. After spending many hours to troubleshoot this issue it turns out that running my commands in `prod` mode actually solved the issue:

```
app/console my:custom:command --env=prod
```